# How to import only parent node leaving all the child nodes from xml file using powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing

I had a xml file somewhat like this

```
  <parent>
  <child1>
    <subchild11/>
    <subchild12/>
   </child1>
   <child2>
    <subchild21/>
    <subchild22/>
   </child2>
  </parent>
```

I want to import only parent node(with arguments if any) without child nodes. Then I want to create a new xml with this parent node and add child to my wish.
I don't want to create the parent node using CreateNode().

Is it possible? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the XML and then remove all children from the parent node.

```bsh
$xmlDocument = [Xml](Get-Content 'file.xml')
$parent = $xmlDocument.ChildNodes[0]
# Remove all children
while ($parent.FirstChild -ne $null) {
     $parent.RemoveChild($parent.FirstChild)
}
```

And then, you can just add children to it:

```bsh
# Add new child nodes
$parent.AppendChild(...)
$parent.AppendChild(...)
```

**Edit**: `$parent.RemoveAll()` also removes attributes of the parent (very confusing, I must admit), so I replaced it with a loop to remove all children.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
This does solve my problem which I just figured it out.
I am looking for more efficient one.

Comment: @srikanthpeetha You mean that it shouldn't parse all the XML, or what do you mean with 'more efficient'? If that is the case then you'll probably want to use a regular expression or something like that. I don't think there's any XML parser that supports partial parsing.

Comment: Yes I couldn't find any xml parser as well.
By the way $parent = $xmlDocument.ChildNodes[0] throwing error saying Childnodes doesn't support indexing

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach uses the third parameter of ImportNode, called "deep". Set to $true it copies all descendant nodes but set to $false, it only copies attributes. See the Microsoft Developer Network page
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode(v=vs.110).aspx

When the input is a DocumentElement and "deep" is $true

> The descendants of the source element and its specified attribute
>   nodes are recursively imported and the resulting nodes reassembled to
>   form the corresponding subtree.
>
> Note: Default attributes are not copied. If the document being
>   imported into defines default attributes for this element name, those
>   are assigned.

When "deep" is $false,

> Specified attribute nodes of the source element are imported, and the
>   generated XmlAttribute nodes are attached to the generated XmlElement.
>
> Note: Default attributes are not copied. If the document being
>   imported into defines default attributes for this element name, those
>   are assigned.

The following code shows this approach in action:

```
$inxml = [xml] @"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="myfile.xsl" ?>
<bookstore specialty="novel">
  <book style="autobiography">
    <author>
      <first-name>Joe</first-name>
      <last-name>Bob</last-name>
      <award>Trenton Literary Review Honorable Mention</award>
    </author>
    <price>12</price>
  </book>
  <book style="textbook">
    <author>
      <first-name>Mary</first-name>
      <last-name>Bob</last-name>
      <publication>Selected Short Stories of
        <first-name>Mary</first-name>
        <last-name>Bob</last-name>
      </publication>
    </author>
    <editor>
      <first-name>Britney</first-name>
      <last-name>Bob</last-name>
    </editor>
    <price>55</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
"@

$outxml1 = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument
$outxml2 = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument

$inxml.bookstore

# third parameter of ImportNode is $true for 'deep copy'
# where descendants are copied fully
# see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode(v=vs.110).aspx
# The descendants of the source element and its specified
# attribute nodes are recursively imported and the resulting
# nodes reassembled to form the corresponding subtree.
$outnode1 = $outxml1.ImportNode($inxml.bookstore, $true)
$outxml1.AppendChild($outnode1)
$outxml1
$outxml1.Save("N:\temp\xml_desc.xml")

# third parameter of ImportNode is $false for "not a 'deep copy'"
# from the above reference:
# Specified attribute nodes of the source element are imported, 
# and the generated XmlAttribute nodes are attached to the 
# generated XmlElement.
$outnode2 = $outxml2.ImportNode($inxml.bookstore, $false)
$outxml2.AppendChild($outnode2)
$outxml2
$outxml2.Save("N:\temp\xml_nodesc.xml")

Write-Host "Ends"
```

The output file xml_desc.xml is:

```
<bookstore specialty="novel">
  <book style="autobiography">
    <author>
      <first-name>Joe</first-name>
      <last-name>Bob</last-name>
      <award>Trenton Literary Review Honorable Mention</award>
    </author>
    <price>12</price>
  </book>
  <book style="textbook">
    <author>
      <first-name>Mary</first-name>
      <last-name>Bob</last-name>
      <publication>Selected Short Stories of
    <first-name>Mary</first-name><last-name>Bob</last-name></publication>
    </author>
    <editor>
      <first-name>Britney</first-name>
      <last-name>Bob</last-name>
    </editor>
    <price>55</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

while xml_nodesc.xml is:

```
<bookstore specialty="novel" />
```

This appears to do what the OP required.

I hope this helps someone even though it will be much too late to help the OP.